# How to remove the application specific data, in Android, from code level?

Tags: java, android

How to remove the application specific data, in Android, from code level?

Something similar to "Clear Data" and "Clear Cache" button in application settings.

Something like, `myAppID.clearData()` or `myAppID.clearCache()`?

I couldn't find any reference, is there anything like this?

Comment: may be try to remove the database and sharedprefs and also files folder if exists from internal folder \data\data where your app is...

Comment: Is there any built in function provided by Google?

Comment: you can reach that folder by calling getFilesDir();

Comment: as some one said above,,just clear db, preferences and files could remove the data...

Answer (score 0):

**To cleare application data**

```
SharedPreferences settings = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("cda-preferences", Context.MODE_PRIVATE); 
        settings.edit().clear().commit();
```

**To delete database**

```
context.deleteDatabase(DATABASE_NAME);
```